# Dojo Chart Legend - Position at top rather than bottom (default)

Tags: charts, dojo, position, location, legend

Dojo Chart by default places the legend at the bottom of the chart. I would like to place the legend at the top of the chart right under the chart title, above the actual chart.

Can anyone share some code on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1**

Hi there!
After fiddleing arrauon with a chart, the Title and it's Legend i would say, easiest way to put the Legend between the Title and the Chart is not to use the Title from the chart itself, but to write the title seperatly into a div like:

```
<div id="ChartTitel" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:15pt;color:orange;width:100%;
border-bottom:4px double blue; padding-bottom:4px; margin:0px;text-
align:center">Production</div>
```

Here's the fiddel with the whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/mbgvL/

Regards

Comment: I did use the domConstruct before posting and as you suggested, but that places the legend ABOVE the title, not between the title and the chart.

Any other ideas/code samples to put the legend between the title and the chart?

Comment: And I should have also said that even if I play with the margins, etc and get it moved under the title, the chart is not drawn properly, meaning the X marker values are now inside the bars, rather than below the line

Comment: Updated my text for you - have a look